# Packet Filter (PF) firewall logging

Tags: security, firewall

I have PF configured and working with rule sets that are logged.

Where is PF logging to? How do I check these logs? How do I configure them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packet filter doesn't log on any file. It does log on a network interface named `pflog0` (a special device in Unix-lang), see

```
man pf.conf
```

You turn on this interface with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo ifconfig pflog0 create
```

You suppress it with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo ifconfig pflog0 destroy
```

You can follow what does packet filter logs on this interface with
`tcpdump` or `wireshark`.

Ex. :

```
/usr/bin/sudo tcpdump -i pflog0
```

If you want to go any further with PF and without writing your own configuration files, I highly recommand to test [Murus](https://www.murusfirewall.com/murus/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally the PF log file would be stored in:

```
/var/log/
```

to tcpdump for example you might do:

```
tcpdump -n -e -ttt -i pflog1
```

for more info do:

```
man pflog
```

Comment: I checked var log not there. I don't have that interface I am comfortable with that tcpdump command ; I do have a dev pf I'm not sure if that's related ;

Comment: No wait damit it's osx 10.9 I forgot something I knew it

Comment: BTW — you might be interested in this [nice/simple frontend for PFLists](http://www.hanynet.com/pflists/index.html)

Comment: I dear god more bash script bombs hey you shady fellow I need cs13 do you have a copy

Answer (score 0):

For macOS 10.12 the tcpdump command for the logs appears to be broken. Wireshark can be used or Pfloggerd see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7905793